# CSS hover on a link list item

Tags: css, list, hover

I have the unorder list like so...

```
<div class="social">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Find Me <img src="images/facebookGrey.png" width="50" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;" class="facebook" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and what I am trying to do is setup a hover so when the user hovers over that list item the image changes.

here is the css I have tried..

```
.social ul img.facebook a:hover{
    background-image:url(images/facebook.png);
    width:50px;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: And that doesn't work... how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is inside the link, not the other way around. Also, you can't change the source of the image via CSS. Setting the background *will* work, but the source will be on top of it. From the looks of your image names, you won't see any effect.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="social">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Find Me</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```css
.social ul a {
    background-image: url(images/facebookGrey.png);
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
.social ul a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/facebook.png);
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks...but would I target just that link item? I've added a class to the link, `<li><a href="#" class="facebook">Find Me</a></li>` and did this to the css `.social ul a.facebook` and `.social ul a.facebook:hover` and that didnt work :(

Comment: It should work. I don't see anything wrong with what you've typed here. Make sure everything is spelled correctly.

Comment: oh it does work, but im trying to target just that one because I will have multiple list items hence the class='facebook'

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
.social ul a:hover img.facebook
```

since the image is inside the anchor.

However, it may be better to remove the `img` tag all together and just use the anchor and set it's `background-image` property.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing background images with actual images.

Set the background image of the `<a>` to `images/facebookGrey.png`, and then change the background image on hover.